# Is it possible to make selenium to work even if the session is locked and even if the user disconnects from the virtual machine

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using a Virtual machine and my script are packaged in jar and a batch file kicks this jar which runs the scripts. Everything works fine but if in case the virtual machine where the test is run gets locked and i come back and see the rest of the tests are failed.

- I am using RDP to connect to the virtual machine
- Using Selenium 2.42 with IE

Comment: What user is logged in at this point?

Comment: Its the admin user with full access to the remote VM

Answer (score 1):

1) Please read the below

http://www.allianceglobalservices.com/executing-automation-suite-on-disconnectedlocked-machines/#.VA7gG6pDt0x

Hope will help you.

Comment: Hi Abhinav, thanks for this but I had already tried this option but with no luck. I am using Win8 machine.

Comment: Also, this link seems to be broken now.

Comment: That's sad. And if only Google, etc. cached that page somewhere so we can pull from it to make a back up.

Comment: Luckily, looks like it's available via wayback: https://web.archive.org/web/20140924124140/http://www.allianceglobalservices.com/blog/executing-automation-suite-on-disconnectedlocked-machines

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use RDP? Are you able to use VNC instead?

If you use VNC, you can access the remote machine without interfering with the run.

I have CI tests that run in a VM this way. Using VNC instead of RDP I can drop in and out as need be. With RDP, I can't.

Although, that may not solve your locking problem. How is the session locking? Manually, or due to some sort of inactivity timeout? You may also need to adjust the settings on your VM to prevent it locking.

Comment: Yes, even i feel that VNC would be the ideal solution for this. But RDP is the preferred option for now. The locking happens due to inactivity timeout. as you rightly mentioned I understand that we need to set the timout setting set a 'not to lock'. Will try with VNC option and keep you all updated.